# Is there a way to make Visual Studio generate internal methods instead of public methods by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio

By default, Visual Studio generates public methods for C#

However, I would like my methods to be internal by default.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. It's public by default and not possible to change it.

Comment: This is not correct.  Depending on the context, Visual Studio will apply different access modifiers.

Comment: My answer was related to the direct question. But what you say it is of course through, VS applies different modifiers depending on the context. For instance event handlers are private.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

In C++ class methods are private by default.
In C# class methods are private by default, but struct methods are public by default.

Are either of these cases the one you are concerned about?

Could you be wondering about what symbols are available to things that use a dll you are creating?

Answer (score 0):

When  you say VS generates public methods, Which feature are you talking about?

1. We have "Generate from usage" in which you type some random method name,

this.notExistingMethod();

You will get a Smart Tag(a little Red box) under notExistingMethod (Assuming you have VS 2010). This will help you generate a method with signature "public void notExistingMethod(){}".

2.You have "Extract Method" for some languages like C#, under refactoring.

Both these options by default create private methods or the least required access wil be given in case of Generate form Usage.

Which type of Method generation are you talking about?